# How to use memcpy to set 2 hex byte data in char array

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

I have a need to store the hex value from a character array `x[11]` to a memory space: `char* content`.
The character array has contents like:

```
{'b', '5', 'a', '8', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', '7', '\n'}
```

And I need to save the ten elements except the `\n`. The following is how I did it:

```
char *content = (char *)calloc(msg_len, sizeof(char));
memcpy(content , x, 10);
```

The memory space output ended up to be in ASCII format:

```
62(b) 35(5) 61(a) 38(8) 61(a) ...
```

But what I hoped it to show in the memory is:

```
b5 a8 ae ab c7
```

Just like what it is in character array, shown above.

What steps can I take to to solve that?

Comment: You need the `"%x"` format specifier. BTW, double quotes denote `char[x]`s, single quotes denote `char`s.

Comment: You hoped memcpy() would change an ASCII hex string into binary bytes for you?  Nope:(

Comment: Characters and integers are no different when it comes down to the byte level. It depends on how they're interpreted. A good example is a buffer overflow attack where a user input is interpreted as runnable code, for example.

Comment: can you change your char array ?, to e.g. {0xb5, 0xa8, 0xae ... }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char x[] = {'b', '5', 'a', '8', 'a', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', '7', '\n'};
    unsigned long long a;
    unsigned char b[5];
    sscanf(x, "%llx\n", &a);

    b[0] = a >> 32;
    b[1] = (a >> 24);
    b[2] = (a >> 16);
    b[3] = (a >> 8);
    b[4] = a ;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%x ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes! this gave me what I need. Thanks jayant